# Is this the Right Way to Perserve Owners, Permissions and Attributes when copying files with robocopy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, ntfs, robocopy

> **Note:** This example is making a copy of an existing directory to an non-existing prior to copying directory.
>
> **Note:** When my [scheduled tasks were giving me an error](https://superuser.com/questions/898718/clicking-display-all-running-tasks-in-the-task-manage-yeilds-catastrophic-failur), this is how I went about attempting to resolve it.

## Step 1: Copying the Files to the Destination Directory

```
robocopy C:\sourceDir C:\destDir *.* /copy:DATSOU /e
```

**Copying the files...**

## Step 2: Copying the Permissions to the Destination Directory

```
robocopy C:\sourceDir\ C:\destDir *.* /mir /secfix /sec
```

**Copy the permissions to the files in the destination directory**

> **Note:** Remember that the [[/mir]] command can delete folders in the destination directory if they are in the source directory, but not in the destination directory.

## Step 3: Verifying the permissions using powershell

This can be verified using powershell:

```
Get-ACL "C:\sourceDir\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" | Format-List

Get-ACL "C:\destDir\GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" | Format-List
```

...and comparing the outputs...with diff or some similar tool to do a spot check  (of course the path line isn't going to match, but the rest of it should).

## Step 4: Spot Check attributes

Running `ls` on the directory in powershell should show the attributes of each file.

Comment: why do you make it two step copying? /sec is sufficient to copy and preserve permissions.
BE CAREFUL WITH /mir parameter! It will remove files from original place if you make changes in destination.

Comment: @strongline Because I read here http://yakupkorkmaz.info/?p=12 that this is what you must do to include the ACLs (but I believe I also saw it in the documentation from Microsoft).  I usually use `\l` to test it out first; is there a better alternative to using `\mir` ?

Comment: The link given didn't say to copy with /e then /sec. It just said that you can use /sec to copy permissions as well. Actually if you want to copy owner info too, /sec won't be enough, use copy:DATO. 
As for /mir, it is short for mirror. So the sync will be two-way. If you delete a file @destination, that deletion will be replicated to source, and the file will be forever gone.